# Webpack generates 20k line of code from

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

My Webpack is working but the compiled file is over 20k line of javascript. I couldn't find anything wrong in my setting. I would appreciate if anyone can take a look these settings. Thanks

HTML

```
<script src="/minjs/component.min.js"></script>
```

package.json

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.10.4",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.9.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.11.1",
    "webpack": "^1.13.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.2.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.2.1"
  }
```

webpack.config.js

```
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: './js/component.js',
  output: {
    path: __dirname + "/minjs",
    filename: "component.min.js"
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [

      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['react']
        }
      }

    ]
  }
};
```

React file

```
    var React = require('react');
    var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

    var component = React.createClass({
        getInitialState: function() {
            return {
                btnColor: false
            };
        },
        render: function(){
            return (
                <div>
                    <FloorContainer />
                    <Panel />    
                </div>
            );
        }
    });


    ReactDOM.render( <component /> , document.getElementById('component') );
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: The compiled file is way to huge. It has over 20k line of code

Comment: Replace 'exclude: /node_modules/,' with 'exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/, and see if it helps

Answer (score 0):

It is likely packaging React and React-DOM into the compiled output.

Comment: Is there a way to avoid compiling them but still require them as dependencies?

Comment: add `externals: {
        "react": "React",
        "react-dom": "ReactDOM"
    }` to your webpack config file, and provide those separately via a script/cdn